Multiple Shalom Zachor's
Iv'e heard of a custom, that when a baby boy is born and is unwell (i.e. in the ICU), to make a Shalom Zachor every week until the bris is performed. What could be the source for such a thing?

There is a custom to make it once, the Friday night before the Bris, according to https://www.yeshiva.org.il/ask/100748

Multiple sources that discuss Shalom Zachor mention a Tosafos in Bava Kama 80a that it's meant to celebrate the fact that the newborn escaped from his mother's womb.
שסעודת שלום זכר עושין בשביל שנמלט ממעי אמו כמבואר בתוס' (ב"ק פ.)
If one takes this to mean that we're celebrating his survival, I guess one could do that every week until he's strong enough to have a bris.
Lots of sources here.
